# touchableHighlight is not working in react-native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

In my code, i have used `TouchableHighlight` with `Icon` inside it. But when i click on it, nothing happens.It looks like an image. The effect of `TouchableHighlight` is not rendering.  This projects is done using react native with typescript.

But, the same code is working in fine and the effect of the `TouchableHighlight` in nicely rendere in react-native with javascript.

Here is the code.

`<TouchableHighlight 
     style={styles.plusIconView} 
     onPress={ () => this.signIn() }>

         <Icon  name="plus" color="white"size={28} />                               </TouchableHighlight>`

this is the style class

`plusIconView: {
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#42d4f4',
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginLeft: "5%"
    }`

the function `signIn` is implemented correctly. How can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. above code is in a separate component (ProfileCard). I insert it to a `View` in App.tsx . In that `View`, need to give style of `flex:1` as follows.

`<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ProfileCard />
 </View>`

It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `console.log("Button touched")` instead of `this.signIn()`? To be sure that Typescript code is compiled correctly. Next step is to find what is `this` in Typescript version. In vanilla javascript `this` refers to execution context, whereas in typescript it refers to more intuitive lexical scope, so you can:

1. Try to refactor and call the function without `this`
2. Or pass function through redux props and call it as `this.props.onPress()`.

Comment: I did as you told above. Then i'm getting the output, when the component is loading. Not when i press the button. Also the touch effect of `touchableHighlight` is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

can you replace your style object with style={{ flex: 1 }} and try if it works.

```
  <TouchableHighlight style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={ () => console.log('test')} >
<Icon  name="plus" color="white"size={28} /> 
</TouchableHighlight>
```